# Bootstrap and Centering a Webpage

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, dreamweaver

I am trying to make a simple webpage in Dreamweaver CC using Bootstrap. I cannot figure out how to make the displayed webpage be centered in the browser. The page just stays left justified. Here is the code I am trying to use:

**HTML5 & CSS**

```css
#banner {
    background-image: url(../images/2000%20x%20150_Bubble_Final_Crop.jpg);
    height: 150px;
}
body {
    width: 1200px;
}
h1 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-top: 25px;
    font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", 
    Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: 58pt;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 24px #D7DC23;
    text-align: center;
}
.container-fluid {
    margin: 0 auto;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Pixinsight Basics</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <section class="row">

    <header id="banner">
    <h1>Pixinsight Basics</h1>
    </header>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
    <p>Hello my fellow astronomers. I have chosen to use Pixinsight
 as my primary processing software. Like you (probably) I have sifted
 around the internet looking for information/tutorials on how to use
 Pixinsight. While this is by no means a comprehensive data set on
 how to use Pixinsight, it should at least get you up and running. 
I have divided this information into 3 distinct processing areas of 
interest:</p>
<ul>
  <li>
    <!--[if !supportLists]--><!--[endif]-->
    Calibration</li>
  <li>
    <!--[if !supportLists]--><!--[endif]-->
    Linear</li>
  <li>
    Non–Linear</li>
</ul>
<p>Just click on one of the buttons below and it will
 take you to your area of interest.</p>
</div>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>


    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </section>
    </div> <!--container-fluid-->

    </body>
</html>
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: .container-fluid getting the full width of the device. If you are not defining a width and you also need to use full width don't define styles for .container-fluid class. Other thing is if you are do not need to use fluid width and you are focus on fixed width, use .container class and its default width is 1170px and you can override it if needed.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, remove the body width, and add width to container-fluid the result being this **css:**

```css
#banner {
  background-image: url(../images/2000%20x%20150_Bubble_Final_Crop.jpg);
  height: 150px;
}
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
h1 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding-top: 25px;
  font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", 
    Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
  font-size: 58pt;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 24px #D7DC23;
  text-align: center;
}
.container-fluid {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Pixinsight Basics</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <section class="row">

    <header id="banner">
    <h1>Pixinsight Basics</h1>
    </header>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
    <p>Hello my fellow astronomers. I have chosen to use Pixinsight
 as my primary processing software. Like you (probably) I have sifted
 around the internet looking for information/tutorials on how to use
 Pixinsight. While this is by no means a comprehensive data set on
 how to use Pixinsight, it should at least get you up and running. 
I have divided this information into 3 distinct processing areas of 
interest:</p>
<ul>
  <li>
    <!--[if !supportLists]--><!--[endif]-->
    Calibration</li>
  <li>
    <!--[if !supportLists]--><!--[endif]-->
    Linear</li>
  <li>
    Non–Linear</li>
</ul>
<p>Just click on one of the buttons below and it will
 take you to your area of interest.</p>
</div>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>


    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </section>
    </div> <!--container-fluid-->

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Many Thanks Jishnu. Did the trick. Not sure how it works, but I will try and figure it out.

Comment: Use .container class instead adding width to .container-fluid

Comment: yeah right , `container-fluid using for fluid desgins

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove body rule

```
body {
    width: 1200px;
}
```

and also container-fluid rule

```
.container-fluid {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

from your CSS. Replace class `col-sm-6` to `col-sm-12` and also add a class `text-center` to this div. 
And if you want some gutter on left and right use class `container` instead of `container-fluid`. choice is your's. But I suggest you to use `container` class because it's suit your need.

The final look:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Regent</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
#banner {
    background-image: url(../images/2000%20x%20150_Bubble_Final_Crop.jpg);
    height: 150px;
}

h1 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-top: 25px;
    font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", 
    Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: 58pt;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 24px #D7DC23;
    text-align: center;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
  <section class="row">

    <header id="banner">
    <h1>Pixinsight Basics</h1>
    </header>

    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
    <p>Hello my fellow astronomers. I have chosen to use Pixinsight
 as my primary processing software. Like you (probably) I have sifted
 around the internet looking for information/tutorials on how to use
 Pixinsight. While this is by no means a comprehensive data set on
 how to use Pixinsight, it should at least get you up and running. 
I have divided this information into 3 distinct processing areas of 
interest:</p>
<ul>
  <li>
    <!--[if !supportLists]--><!--[endif]-->
    Calibration</li>
  <li>
    <!--[if !supportLists]--><!--[endif]-->
    Linear</li>
  <li>
    Non–Linear</li>
</ul>
<p>Just click on one of the buttons below and it will
 take you to your area of interest.</p>
</div>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>


    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </section>
    </div> <!--container-fluid-->

</body>
</html>
```